# What should you do if you have misplaced your previous tax returns?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

What is your best option if you have misplaced those previous returns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call or write in for a copy of your transcripts?

http://www.irs.gov/individuals/article/0,,id=110571,00.html

Of if you need the exact return itself

http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc156.html